# Mask Slug in Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I am trying to mask a url of a show action in a controller with an id to just "sample" but it won't mask:

```
get '/sample' => redirect("/posts/2"), :as => '/sample'
```

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: You're trying to redirect the user to `/posts/:id` when they hit: `/sample`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :
`get  "/sample" => "posts#show", id: 2`